# ViewContainerRef, Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, dom, components

I want to prepend some dynamic html. ViewContainerRef by default appends html after the element which calls it. So help me to better understand viewcontainer, native element and viewcontainer reference.I used ViewContainerRef to create a drop-down and calendar component but now i need more flexibility with it. I need to use it's index feature and need to prepend elements.